# Silverlight ApplicationLifetimeObjects vs Application ResourceDictionary

Tags: silverlight

In a Silverlight application what is the difference between adding objects to ApplicationLifetimeObjects vs the Application ResourceDictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If memory serves me right, the ApplicationLifetimeObjects implement the interface [IAplicationLifeTimeAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.iapplicationlifetimeaware(v=vs.95).aspx) and [IApplicationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.iapplicationservice(v=vs.95).aspx)

Those objects are supposed to handle application's lifetime events, while resources just "are" - if my understanding is correct.